# How can I access a variable from another script in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to be able to use a variable from one script in another script. My goal is to allow me to reference the *particleScale* variable and use it to affect the size of the object connected to the second script. I also want to later reference other variables from other scripts. There also will be several instances of each object. This is my first script;

```
public class Particle : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float particleSize;
    public Transform particle;

    void Start()
    {
        particle.localScale *= particleSize;
    }
}
```

This is my second;

```
public class Magnetic : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform magnetic;

    void Start()
    {
        magnetic.localscale *= Particle.particleSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are more Particles? There are more Magnetic? If so how do you determin to which instance to reference?

Comment: The magnetic is a child of the particle.

Comment: [Please refrain from posting the same question again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72751773/how-do-i-access-a-variable-from-another-script-for-multiple-objects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Particle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Particle instance;
    public float particleSize;
    public Transform particle;

    void Awake()
    {
      instance = this;
    }
    void Start()
    {
        particle.localScale *= particleSize;
    }
}


public class Magnetic : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public Transform magnetic;

    void Start()
    {
        magnetic.localscale *= Particle.instance.particleSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider improving your answer. _[Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)_

Comment: This is basically a singleton. Although it is important to note that you don't want to use singletons for a lot of different things. It is okay if you use it for something like a sound manager, in which case you know it will only be called in specific events and doing a very specific thing (usually changing audioclips and playing different sounds etc). 

The code can get messy if you use too many of them and can lead to bugs which can be hard to find later down the line!

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you don't want your variables to be public.

You really want to have those variables as private and access them through a public method.

If you need to access your variables from the Unity Inspector, it is still a better idea to use *[SerializeField]*:

```
public class Particle : MonoBehaviour
{

    private float particleSize;
    [SerializeField] private Transform particle;

    void Start()
    {
        particle.localScale *= particleSize;
    }

    public float GetParticleSize() {
         return particleSize;
    }
}
```

And the way you call them from a different class could be through the usage of FindObjectOfType<> like others have said *or* you could create a gameobject with the script attached to it and create a public reference to it in the script of your second gameObject and assign it in the inspector!

```
public class Magnetic : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform magnetic;
    public GameObject particleOb;

    void Start()
    {
        magnetic.localscale *= particleOb.GetComponent<Particle>().GetParticleSize;
    }
}
```

In this last way of doing it you basically assign the particle GameObject in the inspector and grab the script from its components. This method also allows you to have multiple objects with few modifications on each object, but still calling the same methods!

Answer (score -1):

There are a few ways to do it,

1. Using the `FindObjectOfType()`

   ```cs
   public class Magnetic : MonoBehaviour
   {
       public Transform magnetic;
       Particle particle

       void Start()
       {
           particle = FindObjectOfType<Particle>();
           magnetic.localscale *= particle.particleSize;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Using a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern (only if you are just going to have a single object of type Particle)

   ```cs
   public class Particle : MonoBehaviour
   {
       public static Particle Instance;
       public float particleSize;
       public Transform particle;

       void Awake() {
           if (Instance != null) {
               Destroy(gameObject);
           } else {
               Instance = this;
           }
       }

       void Start()
       {
           particle.localScale *= particleSize;
       }
   }
   ```

Then the class will globally accessible from `Particle.Instance`, so you can use any public methods from it or in your case the `Particle.Instance.particleSize`.